# Help with T4 and Schema Information

Tags: schema, t4

I am trying to create a data access layer using t4 and C#. I would like to be able to provide a DAL where I can access any database. The problem I am having is with some of the schema information. I am able to retrieve some information like column and table names but I would also like other information like the name of the primary key field, the primary key value. What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting Microsoft SQL Server, Server Management Objects ([SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)) is the best option. Here is an [example](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/01/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-crud-stored-procedures/).